# The sum of the solutions of $x^3 ≡ 8 \mod q$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $q$ be a prime equal to $1 \mod 12$ and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots , \lambda_k$ denote the solutions of $x^3 ≡ 8 \mod q$.

How would I find the sum of these solutions $\mod q$? I'm completely stuck on this, is it something to do with Fermat's?

Comment: for any monic polynomial, the sum of the roots is (negative) the coefficient of the second highest term.

Comment: *Vieta's relations* are valid over any field.

Comment: $x^3-8 = (x-2) ((x+1)^2 + 3)$ and thankfully q is chosen such that -3 is a square mod q by quadratic reciprocity, so all its roots lie in the field.

Comment: You also need to show all roots lie in $\mathbb{F}_p$, which can be checked by factoring one of the obvious roots $x = 2$, and then you are left to check that $x^2 + 2x + 4$ has roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ if its discriminant $-12 = -3 \cdot 2^2$ is a perfect square. Reciprocity can be useful here.

Comment: Not following some of the comments here.  You only need $q\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ to get all three cube roots of $8$ in $\mathbb F_q$.  After all, $2$ is certainly one of the roots and since $3\,|\,q-1$ we know there is a non-trivial cube root of $1$.  For instance, with $q=19$ the cube roots of $8$ are $\{2,3,14\}$.

Comment: Hm yes that's a nice way to look at it without mentioning reciprocity, but using the cyclicity of the unit group.

Answer (score 0):

Your sum has the form $x_0 (\sum_{z \ in G} z)$, where $x_0$ is one solution, and $G=\{z^3=1\}$ is a subgroup of units. This is non trivial because $3 \mid q-1 = |\left ( \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}\right )^* |$. Take a $1\neq \lambda \in G$, and convince yourself that $\lambda S =S \pmod q$. This yields $(\lambda -1)S= 0 \pmod q$, thus $S=0$ because of $\lambda\neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

In each case the number of solutions is three because the equation $x^3-8=0$ has three roots in some extension of the prime field $\mathbb F_q$. Furthermore
$$x^3-2^3=(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)\Rightarrow\begin{cases}x_1=2\\x_2=-1+\sqrt{1-4}\\x_3=-1-\sqrt{1-4}\end{cases}$$
 We see explicitement that the required sum is equal to zero.